# estimate h2o glm coefficients by a categorical variable level

Tags: r, glm, h2o

I would like to estimate coefficient for a predictor by a categorical variable level in h2o glm. For example, if my data frame has product price (continuous variable) and product type (categorical variable), then I want to estimate a coefficient for price by product. In SAS, you can easily accomplish this by specifying model effect as price*type. How can I do the same in h2o or R?

There is an interactions() function, but it cannot handle interaction between a continuous and categorical variables. Any tips to get around this problem?

Many thanks,

Comment: Check out the interactions argument of the h2o.glm function

Comment: Interactions() works well when both are categorical variables, but not when one of them is a continuous variable (e.g. price).

Comment: Yes, interactions() is for categorical variables only.  Thanks for clarifying my oversight there!

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = rnorm(100,0,1)
x2 = as.factor(rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 25))
y = as.factor(rep(0:1, each = 50))
data = data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, y = y)
```

Interactions can be specified using a ":" in the formula argument

```
# glm base example
fit <- glm(data = data, y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, family = "binomial")
print(fit)
```

Using h2o.glm pairwise interactions can be specified by passing column indices to the interactions argument

```
# h2o.glm example
library("h2o")
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
data.hex = as.h2o(data)
h2o_fit <- h2o.glm(x = 1:2, y = 3, training_frame = data.hex, family = "binomial", interactions = 1:2)
h2o_fit@model$coefficients_table
h2o.shutdown(prompt = F)
```

Comment: Peter - Thank you for the response. Aren't both x1 and x2 in your example categorical variables? Interactions() works well when both are categorical variables, but not when one of them is a continuous variables (e.g. price).